# ActiveMQ Code working in Windows but Fails in CentOS

Tags: java, jms, centos, activemq-classic

I'm working with a a framework that has a Core application, and secondary applications that all communicate using JMS via ActiveMQ (through Camel). It all seems to work fine on Windows, but the moment I moved it to our CentOS environment it failed. Let me note that our guy who programmed it and who was our ActiveMQ guy has left so I don't know quite how to diagnose the problem. It seems to be establishing a connection but then does nothing else. It is supposed to begin an exchange of messages but it doesn't. When I set logging to DEBUG I get messages saying "urlList connectionList:[]" and "waiting x ms before attempting connection" as though it's not connecting. I've made sure there's no firewall, there's no security policy to block it, ActiveMQ is shown to be running. I've tried everything I can think of but I have no idea what the problem could be. Any recommendations?

Answer (score 0):

try testing ActiveMQ via the web console to make sure it's functioning properly.  next, try connecting remotely via JMX and verify that works as well.  It's likely an environment issue that will be difficult to diagnose via the info given...

see these pages for more information...

http://activemq.apache.org/web-console.html

http://activemq.apache.org/jmx.html